# Setting navigation back button (leftBarButtonItem) only once

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set in almost each page a custom back button and I'm repeating the same code in each page like this;

```
let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "arrow_back"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action:"popBack")
buttonItem.tintColor=UIColor.blackColor()
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem()
```

And I think this is the wrong way for it. So please could you tell what is the best way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various options here.

**1) UIViewController extension**

```
extension UIViewController {

    func brandedBackButton() {

        let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action:"popBack")
        buttonItem.tintColor=UIColor.blackColor()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem
    }
}
```

and then just call in your view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    brandedBackButton()
}
```

**2) Base View Controller Class**

You would basically put a class in between your controllers and the UIViewController.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action:"popBack")
        buttonItem.tintColor=UIColor.blackColor()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem
     }
}
```

and then you would inherit from this BaseViewController instead of standard UIViewController.

```
class YourWhateverViewController: BaseViewController {

//implementation here....
```

}

Both the category and the base class can also accommodate the popBack custom method so you would end up really with literally 10 characters to get this behaviour anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

I've done this by creating a category on UIViewController. In that file I created a method called addBackButton, where you can put your code in once, then expose the method in your .h file. Then in any of your view controller subclasses you can import your category and call [self addBackButton];

Comment: Create a category by going File -> New -> File -> then Select Objective-C file under iOS Source and tap Next, then in File Type select Category and for Class select UIViewController

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a custom UIButton class and reuse it every time you want it.

```
class backButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

convenience init(target: AnyObject?) {
    self.init(image: UIImage(named: "arrow_back"), style: .Plain, target: target, action: "popBack")
    self.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}}
```

just type the following script when you use it:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem(target: self)
```